# Slow performance when doing SQL join on lots of split results

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, join

I have about thirty strings that get passed to my stored procedure which act as the columns of a table I need to manipulate. Each string is delimited and I use a split function to break each one of these strings apart into it's appropriate rows which usually consist of twenty or fewer rows. The split function is quite fast and return a table result with one column being an ID which is the primary key and the other column being the split out value, and from examining the execution plan the thirty splits only take up a fraction of my time. The part that seems to kill my performance is the actual join among those thirty split results sets.

```
DECLARE @WorkingTab TABLE ([ID] INT PRIMARY KEY, [Col1] VARCHAR(255), [Col2] VARCHAR(255), ...)

INSERT INTO @WorkingTab ([ID], [Col1], [Col2], ...)
SELECT
    splitStr1.ID,
    splitStr1.VALUE,
    splitStr2.VALUE,
    .
    .
    .
FROM
    dbo.Split(@Str1, '~') splitStr1
    LEFT JOIN
        dbo.Split(@Str2, '~') splitStr2
    ON splitStr1.ID = splitStr2.ID
    LEFT JOIN
        dbo.Split(@Str3, '~') splitStr3
    .
    .
    .
```

I've tried using inner joins instead of left join which decreased performance slightly. I've tried inserting just the first split result into an indexed temp table then updating the rest of the column values into the appropriate column in the temp table which again resulted in a minor performance decrease. I've tried tried inserting all of the results into a persistent table which also didn't improve performance at all. If anyone has any suggestions on other ways to approach this or just general performance tips, I'm all ears. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that looks a horrible way to accomplish what you want! Can you take a step back and tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: One of the **many** problems with this is indexes cannot be used.  This is a really terrible method and should be reworked.

Comment: You should at least say **what** you're trying to achieve with this code. What is @Str1? The code is unclear.

Comment: The core problem is that I essentially need to get a table of data into a stored proc from a classic ASP web app. I'm pretty far from being a DB guru, so the first thing that came to mind was taking all of the delimited strings, passing them into the SP, splitting them up, then putting them back together into a table to work with. I'll be the first to admit that this looks uglier than all get out and if there's a better way to deal with this I'm happy to take suggestions. As for what @Str1 is, it's just a string variable that's passed in to the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not a good strategy, performance-wise.  User defined functions will never be high performers.  Have you considered submitting your data as an XML document and parsing it in a stored procedure?  I've done that before and it's usually a decent performer.

In regards to your actual question, there may be some ability to optimize your table valued function so that it returns a table variable with a primary key defined, which could improve performance, but really, I recommend changing your upload strategy.

Comment: To paraphraze [JWZ](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247),  I think that using XML will just land you with two problems.  The OP already has strings that can be broken apart programatically.

Comment: XML is well defined, flexible, and natively parsable in SQL Server.  OP is rolling his own instead of using built-in functionality.  I use this sort of thing all the time, and it works pretty well... and is human readable.  Don't think the quote about Regex applies.

Comment: Yep, XML is probably the way to go, then I just avoid all of the ugly joins in the first place. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

The joins will be quite inefficient for thirty table variables as it has to scan each one for every join.  You need to get it to an operation that behaves more like O(N) or O(N log N) - practically, I think this means getting all the outputs sorted and recognized as being sorted by the query optimiser.  I can't think of a way that is simple, clean and compact to to this.  However, one of the following approaches might work:

- Load the output from each split function into a set of temporary tables and create a clustered index on ID for each table.  This might get a reasonably efficient merge join plan and the clustered index builds will be O(N log N) with an effectively O(N) merge join operation.
- Open cursors on each table sorted in order of ID and loop through them all procedurally (i.e. get one row from each of the cursors for every loop iteration).  If the row counts on the output of the functions are reasonably small than this might not be too expensive.  The cursor ops will be somewhat expensive but the query is effectively O(N log N) and the looping operation is O(N).

A better plan might be to do the whole thing procedurally (i.e. avoid the table valued split function).  If the strings can all be sorted by ID as you get them (or possibly as a preliminary step) you can just do the whole thing with string operations.  Peel off the first record from each string and store the tail of the string for the next iteration.

Comment: table variables can have clustered index on id too. `declare @t table(id int primary key)`